# Is it possible to access a local variable, outside the function in mean stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById('sub_id').value;
var address1=document.getElementById('sub').value;
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log('Inside status');
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
         longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    }


});
console.log(latitude);
```

When I am trying to print the above latitude and longitude on outside the function, the value is undefined.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: That's because latitude is declared inside your function, if you want it to have scope outside of the function you would need to declare it above the call to geocoder.geocode.Also, geocoder.geocode looks like it is an async function which means you would need to console.log latitude or what ever programming logic you need inside the if statement contained inside the callback function of geocoder.geocode

Comment: Of course it gets `undefined`. It's the expected result. Declare the variables outside the function and asign them values inside the function. Then you should see the values when logging.

Comment: That won't work @Ionut as the values are retrieved asynchronously

Comment: @DanPantry, of course, if the function is async then he should treat what he wants inside the function or use a `promise` or something.

Comment: create the variable in global scope and assign the latitude value to the global variable. Later access that global variable for further operation.

Comment: I tried that too, but then also it displays undefined

Comment: That won't work @SureshPonnukalai as I just mentioned to Ionut. Please see the answer that Bengi has marked this question as a duplicate of.

Comment: Your log runs before the function execution ends, if the functions it's asynchronous. So you're actually asigning the value to the variable after the `console.log(latitude)`